# Re sorting fetchedresultscontroller once the data is fetched

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a situation where i need to sort the data using multiple `sort descriptors`. I want to sort the data initially with two components which are numbers in descending order. Then I should show the data on the table view sorted with name component and use the `sectionNameKeyPath` to get the sections.

I want the data should be sorted out first with the two specified components and then the result with name. Is this possible using `NSfetchedResultsController`. I am using this `fetchedresultscontroller` in data source for `tableview`. Is there anyway to re sort the `fetchedresultscontroller`?

I can sort it by taking an array and using `sortdescriptor` on that, but I want `fetchedresultscontroller` to show the section details and etc.

Is there any way?

Comment: Why can't you add all the sort descriptors to the fetch request of the FRC?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really sure if I have understood your answer.

But there is a property called `sortDescriptors` in `NSFetchRequest` which you may use it to sort.

And it's an array so you can supply multi `NSSortDescriptor` objects

And if you want to resort it.

I know two ways:

1. Store the result in an array like you said and resort it.
2. Change the `sortDescriptors` and re `performFetch` of the FRC